# Deleting multiple rows in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 1 and NAME ='xyz';
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 2 and NAME ='abc';
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 3 and NAME ='abc';
```

I have multiple delete statements mentioned above. How can I delete them in less statements. Will I have to write 100 delete statements?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
delete from mytable
where (id, name) in ((1, 'xyz'),
                     (2, 'abc'),
                     (3, 'abc'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE
WHERE (ID, NAME) IN (SELECT 1 AS ID, 'xyz' AS NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 AS ID, 'abc' AS NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 AS ID, 'abc' AS NAME FROM dual);
```

Of course inside subquery you could use any select (for instance from global temporary table).

Answer (score -2):

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE 
  WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3) AND NAME IN ('XYZ', 'ABC');
```

If your id field is unique then use:

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is not necessarily accurate.  A row where `Id = 1` and `Name = 'abc'` would meet your criteria, but not his.